# variable scope in C language

Tags: c, initialization

I was trying to find out the **perfect numbers** between 1 to 500.I was trying running the following program but I was not getting the desired output except when I am initializing the same(i.e.,sum) inside the for loop,I am getting the desired output. What is is it so?

```
int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int num = 1; num <= 500; ++num) {
        for (int i = 1; i < num; ++i) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        if (sum == num) {
            printf("%d, ", num);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `sum` isn't initialized. The first line of the function does it.

Comment: Can you add an example of what the code it supposed to do? Do you need `sum` to be 0 initially for each of the outer iterations?

Comment: huh? can you please define what the behavior was when it was not working and when it was working? include where you placed `sum`

Comment: If you move `int sum = 0;` inside the `for` loop you will of cause get another output as you set `sum` to zero in every loop.

Comment: What is the problem? Can you run the program? Is it producing incorrect output? If so, what's the input, output, and expected output?

Comment: Explain the question correctly as to what you are expecting? What is that you are not able to find out? It will be easy for the other geeks to help you.

Comment: You have mentioned three different versions of this code, but shown only one.  If you want an explanation of the behaviour of each version, provide each version - a vague description is inadequate. You have asserted that it is a matter of scope, but it is a matter of initialisation.  You have also claimed that "_there not much explicit information about this topic_", which is nonsense - the behaviour of the language is _well defined_.  In general, just ask the question rather then providing assertions and propositions about things you know little of.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the definition and initialization of `sum` inside the outer loop body will work fine. `sum` will be reinitialized at the start if each iteration.

Note that you can reduce the time complexity of this function this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int num = 1; num <= 100000; ++num) {
        int i, sum = 1;
        for (i = 2; i * i < num; ++i) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                sum += i + num / i;
            }
        }
        if (i * i == num) {
            sum += i;
        }
        if (sum == num) {
            printf("%d, ", num);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Timed output (`num <= 100000`):

```
1, 6, 28, 496, 8128,

real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.070s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Original code:

```
6, 28, 496, 8128,

real    0m15.582s
user    0m15.249s
sys     0m0.067s
```

EDIT: If by *putting the sum inside the loop*, you mean writing `for (int i = 1, sum = 0; i < num; ++i) {` it does not compile because `sum` is only defined inside the `for` statement, so the test `if (sum == num)` refers to an undefined variable.

Comment: not working if putting the sum inside the loop.I don't why.

Comment: @Arpanjana: what do you mean by *not working* and *putting the sum inside the loop*? Be more concise, add an EDIT to the question with the code that is *not working*